# Using constructor items within a function-based component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm following along to this [PubNub Push Notifications in React-JS](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications-ios-android/) tutorial and everything is going fine up until I add the Constructor to the code as it states in the tutorial. I (think I) know enough about react to know that you cannot use a constructor in a non-class based component.

I can't seem to figure out how I would implement this. It appears that when the tutorial was made, the boilerplate code has since been updated and this constructor is no longer supposed to be used in this way.

*Below is an image of where I am with the code and in the tutorial:*

[image: Image of the function]

Should I just convert this to a class-based component? or will that limit me from using hooks in the future?

(Apologies for lack of react knowledge)

Comment: Looks like Andrii is providing great insights and guidance. If you require any PubNub specific support, please send request with this link included to [PN Support](https://support.pubnub.com)

Comment: I’m just waiting to get back to the project to test it. But I’m sure the answer is correct. Andrii has been very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks:

Why `useRef`?

> The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class. [more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

`this.pubnub` is an instance property of a class, so you have to add it to `useRef` hook.

Why `useEffect`?

> useEffect, adds the ability to perform side effects from a function component [more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook)

Initialization of `PubNubReact` - is a side effect, so you need to add it to `useEffect` hook.

**UPDATE**

*Bad news:* It looks like that `pubnub-react` can't be used with functional components, they have very weird API and they even agree with this (You could read about that in this [issue](https://github.com/pubnub/react/issues/30))

*Good news:* You could use an official [`pubnub`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubnub-react) package in your application and it will work great:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import PubNub from 'pubnub';

function App() {
  const pubnub = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    pubnub.current = new PubNub({...});

    pubnub.current.addListener({
      message(msg) { console.log(msg) }
    });

    pubnub.current.subscribe({ channels: ['channel1'] });

    pubnub.current.publish({ message: 'hello world from react', channel: 'channel1' });
  }, []);

  return (...);
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting this error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pubnub.push.addChannels')

Comment: @NiallLonergan I have updated my answer. Please check it.